# How to prevent the welcome screen from showing up after I close my last notebook? (Ubuntu 11.10, MMA 8.0.4.0)

Tags: front-end, linux

I would like to prevent the welcome screen from showing up after I close my last notebook. This is not an issue on my Windows machine, so I suspect it is system dependent.  I am running Ubuntu 11.10.  Any ideas?

Edit 1:
This only happens when I close the last notebook by clicking on the "x" button.  As Szabolcs pointed out, I can avoid this issue using File -> Quit or Ctrl-Q.  This seems to be a Linux-specific problem.

Comment: You can use File -> Quit to close it for good.

Comment: It works!  I have always assumed that clicking on the "x" button is equivalent to "Quit" (or Ctrl-Q) from the pull-down menu.  From now on I will use the Ctrl-Q shortcut.

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you write something down in the answers section so that I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: If no one will come up with a better suggestion, I will.  But let's wait a day first.  I also find this a bit annoying. In older versions it would pop up a new emtpy notebook when you closed the last one.  Showing the welcome screen is still better.

Comment: Why don't you just disable the welcome screen for good? I don't see it being useful beyond the first few days for a new user...

Comment: @R.M How can I disable the welcome screen for good?

Comment: I miss the new empty notebook :P. I usually use keyboard so I use Ctrl W for closing notebooks, and Ctrl Q to close all session notebooks. Ctrl W closes the welcome screen too.

Comment: @FJRA The welcome screen shows up if I use Ctrl-W to close the last notebook.

Comment: @MichaelWijaya yes, maybe I didn't explain myself well, what I wanted to point out is that the same keys can close both windows, so hitting Ctrl W twice will quit (but if you are already using the keyboard you should use Ctrl Q).

Comment: This is especially annoying because the welcome screen takes like 2 seconds to load.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The screen won't show when you use `File | Quit`, or you can use the shortcut `Ctrl+Q`.

I actually wrote the Wolfram support about this issue, the response said that that window opening is the desired behavior and it's thought to be somewhat of a substitute of not having the "main bar" the Windows version has. In that sense, it is not intended that closing all notebooks also shuts down Mathematica (plus kernel). When I told him that *it's a bug unless you can disable it*, I was told he'll bring the idea up for development at some point. Oh well.

Comment: Yeah, users have no idea about UX … Thanks for reporting a bug!

Answer (score 11):

Upon closing the last notebook *Mathematica* opens the notebook file `MathematicaNavigator.nb` or `MathematicaNavigatorTrial.nb` (if you are using a trial version) or `MathematicaNavigatorStudent.nb` (if you are using a student version). These files reside in `[prefix]/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources`. That path name is hardcoded into the *Mathematica* binary. If *Mathematica* really doesn't have an option to disable the welcome screen completely (it likely doesn't), the only solution I see is to modify the contents of `MathematicaNavigator.nb` to make it exit Mathematica immediately. Before proceeding with modifying that file, **be sure to disable the display of the welcome screen at startup time**.

After you have disabled the welcome screen at startup, either by unchecking "Show at startup" checkbox on the startup screen or by using `Edit | Preferences | System | Show at startup -> New document`, back up the existing `MathematicaNavigator.nb` in case something goes wrong. Delete all code from `MathematicaNavigator.nb` and replace it with the following:

```
Notebook[{
    Cell["", "", CellDynamicExpression :>
        FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"]] 
}]
```

Basically, this represents a notebook with an empty cell having a dynamic handler. It activates when the cell is displayed to user. The handler `FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"]` just sends the *Mathematica* FrontEnd a quit message, just as if you had given the `Ctrl+Q` shortcut. By the way, calling `NotebookClose[]` instead of `FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"]` will always crash Mathematica with SIGSEGV on my machine (Mathematica 8.0.4.0 / Debian Wheezy 64-bit).

Another side effect is an immediate exit when `About | Welcome screen` is diplayed. I believe, this code could be improved to correctly detect circumstances under which `MathematicaNavigator.nb` was called.

Answer (score 9):

Update: Mathematica 10 seems to have resolved this issue, via the "Always Exit after closing last window" option in Preferences->Interface. David, it looks like they actually listened to your suggestion!